# Why an extra integer type among short/int/long?

Tags: c, integer, standards

Until recently I believed that 'long' was the same thing as 'int' because of historical reasons and desktop processors all having at least 32 bits (and had troubles only with that "dupe" since only developing on 32 bits machines).

Reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), I discover that, in fact, the C standard defines the int type to be **at least** an int16, while 'long' is supposed to be at least an int32.

In fact in the list

- Short signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−32767, +32767] range
- Basic signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−32767, +32767] range;
- Long signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−2147483647, +2147483647] range
- Long long signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−9223372036854775807, +9223372036854775807] range;

there are always non-empty intersections, and therefore a duplicate, whatever implementation the compiler and platform choose.

Why did the standard commitee introduced an extra type among what could be as simple as char/short/int/long (or int_k, int_2k, int_4k, int_8k)?

Was that for historical reasons, like, gcc x.x implemented int as 32 bits while another compiler implemented it as 16, or is there a real technical reason I'm missing?

Comment: "processors all having becomed at least 32 bits." --> 100s of million of embedded processors in 2015 use 16-bit `int`.

Comment: ok. editing to deskop processors

Comment: Moreover, there are 100s of millions of 8-bit embedded processors...

Comment: @RegisPortalez And invalidating your own question. C is *universal* language.

Comment: I believe the size of `int` is usually selected first (based on CPU register sizes), with `short`, `long` and `long long` available to provide access to smaller/larger sizes.

Comment: ok I get your objections. The thing is there is obviouly one duplicate in the list char/short/int/long/longlong. And that doesn't depent on the platform. I'll edit the question to make it clear

Comment: It is why is always best approach to use `stdint.h` an its defined types: `uint8_t`, `uin32_t`, etc...

Comment: That one is a duplicate doesn't depend on the platform (for now), but which one is duplicate *does* depend on the platform, so all of these types are needed on one platform or another.

Comment: @LPs: agreed, but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: We are kind of in the same situation as 20 years ago, where 64 bit processors uses 32 bit int (i386 used 16 bit int and 32 bit long for a long time). The difference is that, this time I really don't see any hope that 64 bit int will ever be implemented.

Comment: @user3528438 It will, if C won't phase out...

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Even  8-bit embedded processors will use a 16-bit `int` as C requires a minimal `int` range.

Comment: @chux It was a reply "processors all having becomed at least 32 bits"

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Fair point.

Comment: It is best practice to use C99 types from stdint, like uint8_t, etc. This explicit typing helps to avoid a huge class of potential coding errors.

Comment: @MartinEttl It depends, really. Sometimes you just should not care about the bit-length of your data and work abstract, as you do with floats/doubles. Just apply a common sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, you are absolutely right. Its a problem dependent best practice.

Comment: @user3528438: A typical C implementation will have four kinds of integers: full-size signed, full-size unsigned, small signed, and small unsigned, each with different semantics.  A lot of code is written for a type that behaves as a 32-bit full-sized unsigned; the route to a 64-bit "int" should include defining types whose semantics will mirror those of n-bit full-sized unsigned, *independent of the size of `int`*.  It may also be helpful to have types whose semantics are analogous to short unsigned, again regardless of the size of `int`.

Comment: @user3528438: Using decimals rather than binary for notational convenience, if your utility meter 9950 last month and 0005 now, how much did you use?  If a group had 6000 people last month and 4000 people now, how many people did it gain or lose?  In the first case, wrapping semantics are called for; in the latter case, signed semantics (4000-6000 should not be interpreted as +8000 but as -2000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The central point is that `int/unsigned` is not just another step of integer sizes from `char, short,int, long, long long` ladder.  `int` is special.  It is **the** size that all narrower types promote to and so typically works "best" on a given processor.  So should `int` match `short`, `long` or is wedged distinctly between `short/long` is highly platform dependent.

C is designed to accommodate a *wide* range of processors.   Given that C is 40+ years old is testament to a successfully strategy.

Comment: As pointer by chux, a 16 bits int would not be that good on a 8bits processor. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Regis Portalez An 8-bit processor typically does not have the performance goals of wider processors. So a 16-bit `int` in that environment is "good" enough.

Comment: @RegisPortalez In reality the integer promotion will be optimized out by the compiler in almost all cases if not necessary, so it ends up not being a big deal. And while `int` is *typically* the best, this is of course not guaranteed and you should use `int_fast8_t` etc. if you have specific performance goals.

Comment: OP later addition inquires about "int8, int16, int32, int64".  These are exact width types and not available in, now rare, processors of 9-bit, 12-bit, etc. multiples. e.g. C works on machines with 36-bit `int`.

Comment: And C99 integer types requires 2's compliment representation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any reference on that? I mean, about 'int' being special.

Comment: @user3528438 C99 does not require 2's compliment representation.  Note that types `int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t` are optional.  Highly portable code uses  `int_least8_t, int_least16_t, ...`

Comment: @Regis Portalez C11dr 6.3.1.8 details the "Usual arithmetic conversions" which includes narrower integer type being promoted to `int/unsigned`.  _Integer promotion_ is referenced dozens of places in the the C spec including `...` arguments and _integer constants_.  It is a fundamental aspect of C.

Comment: I found the line indeed: If an
int
can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an
int
;
otherwise,   it   is   converted   to   an
unsigned  int
.   These   are   called   the
integer
promotions
.
48)
All other types are unchanged by the integer promotion

Thanks!

Comment: Is that related to the fact that main returns an int? Or maybe int speaks to users, while default_int_type wouldn't?

Comment: `int` is simply the _go to_ integer type used for _decades_ of code and huge number of libraries.  It was _the_ language's  integer type.  Confident C started in its infancy (pre-standard) days with `char`, `int`, `double`.  By the time of C89 (first wide standard), over a decade of common practices were codified, including `int main()`.